# scp copying to localhost from remote server

Tags: linux, scp

I was wondering whether there's a way to copy files from remote server to localhost after i had already "ssh"ed into the remote host?
i.e. after ssh: "scp file @local:~"
(I know about scp user@remote:~/ .  It's not what i'm looking for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of ssh, you can reuse a connection. See [How To Reuse SSH Connection To Speed Up Remote Login Process](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-reuse-openssh-connection/).

Comment: Just stepped by accidently; pretty cool things. Didn't know that! +1

Comment: Really nice feature, but how is this answering the question?